# SQLite insert command not working with images

Tags: android, android-sqlite

It was working very well. But when i put image broked. Before doesn´t exist "foto". But I need save a property type BLOB. But I dont´t know why is broking.

```
Bitmap bitmap = imageViewProeto.getDrawingCache();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            if(bitmap != null){
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            }
            //byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
            byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();
            bitmap.recycle();


            boolean isOk = validarCampos();
            if(!isOk){
                String query = "INSERT INTO  projetos (nome, descricao, url, foto, voluntario_id ) " +
                        "VALUES ('"+ nomeDigitado +"','"+descricaoDigitada+ "','"+urlDigitada+"',  "+ data +" , " + testeId + ")";

                bancoDados.execSQL(query);
```

Comment: If you added the column foto after you first ran the app, uninstall the app from the device so the database is deleted and then rerun to recreate the database and the table.

Comment: It's not a good idea to store BLOBs in a database. Better store the file paths only.

Comment: you can't use `byte[]` in a `String` query (at lease the way you trying to.). First check how that byte array is converted to a part of query, and you will see why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A blob needs to be inserted as a string of hex numbers enclosed in single quotes and prefixed by x e.g.

```
"INSERT INTO  projetos (nome, descricao, url, foto, voluntario_id ) " +
                    "VALUES ('"+ nomeDigitado +"','"+descricaoDigitada+ "','"+urlDigitada+"',  x'000102030405060708090a0b0c' , " + testeId + ")";
```

- x'000102030405060708090a0b0c' is just an example of the format using some arbritary value that would very likely not be an image.

As such you'd need to convert the byte[] to the respective value. **However**, if you use the SQLiteDatabase [**insert**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) convenience method rather then **execSQL** then the conversion is performed by the method and thus the value can be passed as a byte[].

e.g. you could use :-

```
ContentValues() cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(nome,nomeDigitado);
cv.put(nomeDigitado,descricaoDigitada);
cv.put(foto,data);
cv.put(voluntario_id,testeId);
cv.put(url,urlDigitada); //<<<<< note out of order but the correct SQL will be built
long rowid = bancoDados.insert("projetos",null,cv);
```

- In addition to conveniently handling byte[]'s the insert method also has the fowlling advantages :-

  - it returns the **rowid** of the inserted row or -1 if the row was not inserted.
  - it also offers protection against SQL Injection.
  - it builds the underlying SQL (for insertion via VALUES)

**HOWEVER**, if the byte[] is around 2MB or greater then you will not be able to retrieve the BLOB as there is a 2MB size limit for a Cursor Window (a buffer into which complete rows are placed). There may also be issues with smaller byte[] as the process for retrieving the data can be relatively slow.

It is recommended to rather save the path to the respective image which is stored as a file. However, saving images (byte[]) as BLOBs that are around about 100KB can be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it´s not broking.

Comment: My imageView comes NULL, is it right to get image value?

Bitmap bitmap = imageViewProeto.getDrawingCache();
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                if(bitmap != null){
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                }
                byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();

Comment: @ThunAnFreitasChiu, well getDrawingCache is deprecated I believe but you need to debug to see where the null is coming from  probably place breakpoints on the lines and then running in debug mode. see [Debug your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) if you need to.